# in R, find Cholesky of a crossproduct (e.g. XtX) without forming XtX

Tags: r, lme4

In the lme4 vignette named [Computational Methods](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/Theory.pdf) (if that link doesn't work, go [here](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=lme4) and then click on "Computational Methods") Doug Bates mentions that the Cholesky factorization of XtX can be taken with CHOLMOD without forming XtX (that is, just using Xt)

[image]

(page 18, right after equation 54). Is that functionality visible to users? I looked in the Matrix package and didn't see it, but there are two (other) Cholesky functions.

Typically one loses about half of the digits of precision by forming a crossproduct (XtX) and then continuing to work from there. does CHOLMOD somehow maintain the precision if you pass it just Xt?

Comment: You can do a QR-decomposition of X.

Comment: The QR certainly would make this easier. But, in the lme4 document (linked above) they make it clear the Cholesky is faster for this purpose.